# Unit Test Project: "No connection string could be found in the application config file" even when one is provided in app.config

Tags: c#, unit-testing, database-connection

I'm trying to fix errors on a unit testing projects, one of them is this

```
System.ApplicationException: No connection strings for ConnectionType: VinLog
```

After reviewing the answer on this cuestion..
[Unit Test Project: "No connection string could be found in the application config file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46290707/unit-test-project-no-connection-string-could-be-found-in-the-application-confi)

I have added the connection string to the app.config of the unittesting project as shown below

```xml
     <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Campaigns" connectionString="data source=abcdef-mts11;initial catalog=Campaigns;persist security info=True;user id=blabla;password=bleble;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="VinLog"
        connectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=VinLog;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
```

But still the `VinLog` connection string is not working correctly

What could be causing this ?

**UPDATE**

Here is the code that is firing the exception, on the VSCore.Configuration.Settings.MasterConfig.GetAppSetting method

VSCore is a DLL that is imported into the project.

```cs
private static LoggingLevelSwitch GetLevelSwitch()
{
    /* this is a quick fix, to use a default value, instead of accesing the VinLog database
    logLevel = GetLogLevel("debug");
    levelSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch();
    levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = logLevel;

    return levelSwitch;
    */
    if (levelSwitch == null)
    {
        string configLogLevel = VSCore.Configuration.Settings.MasterConfig.GetAppSetting(applicationName + "LogLevel");//each application can specify it's own log level
        configLogLevel = configLogLevel != null ? configLogLevel.ToLower() : "";
        logLevel = GetLogLevel(configLogLevel);

        levelSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch();
        levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = logLevel;
    }
    return levelSwitch;
}
```

I have also checked and the `app.config` file is in the `bin/Debug` folder and it contains the expected content

Comment: @BasilKosovan I have updated the question with the details you have requested